# making a Binary Search Tree from a Sorted Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list

Hey guys So I am studying programming interview questions and I got stuck in this one.

I am trying to do this recursively but I don't know where to start.

This is the algorithm I have so far:

```
 makeTree(head, tail){
   nodeMid = list/2
   root = nodeMid
   root.left = makeTree(head, nodeMid)
   root.right = makeTree(nodeMid, tail)
```

Do I have the right idea? any input is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem I see immediately and forgive me if I am wrong you are not changing the location of the list for each node.
each time you recursively call

```
makeTree(head, tail){
    nodeMid = list/2;
```

as far as I can see inside the loop you do not change which part of the list goes with the recursive call.  ie
you have an array of ints
myints which has (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
every time the recursion is called it will infinitely fill the binary tree with the number at list/2
you need to change the value of nodeMid with each call, use the head/tail variables you are sending.

you do not want to keep resetting the root node either.  you should be using the "this" operator to set the value of the current node you are looking at.

start being the start of the portion of the array you are looking at
and end being the end of the portion.
the recursive calls would be so.
you also need to add in the boundaries of the recursion

Using a BST with nodes when you create a new node in the tree the left and right nodes would be set to null to start with.  you need to create a new node and call the recursion.

```
Node makeTree(int head, int tail){
    nodeMid = (head+tail)/2;
    this = new Node();
    if(head < nodeMid-1)
    {
        this.left = makeTree(head, nodeMid-1);
    }
    if(nodeMid < tail)
    {        
        this.right = makeTree(nodeMid, tail); 
    }
    this.setValue(list[nodeMid]);
    return this;
}
```

after all the recursion is done you need to set the value of the current node and return that node for the creation.
this will recursively turn a sorted array into a binary search tree.  simply put in the proper list coding for your doubly linked list.

To start the recursion

```
root = makeTree(0, list.length());
```

Comment: Thanks man. Makes sense. Just one question why (head+tail)/2 specially if head and tail are nodes.

Comment: head and tail can not be nodes, you need to be able to do math to find the node between the start and end or head and tail of the section you are looking at.  To get the value from the list I would suggest using the number you are looking at nodeMid and iterate through the linked list to that point using a loop or some other function and then storing the value of that point in the bst

Comment: If my answer helped in anyway please mark the answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some important points:

1. Get the Middle of the linked list and make it root.
2. Recursively do same for left half and right half.

   - Get the middle of left half and make it left child of the root
       created in step 1.
   - Get the middle of right half and make it right child of the
       root created in step 1.

Time complexity: **O(nLogn)** where **n** is the number of nodes in `Linked List`.

Answer (score 0):

**Logic**

```
1) Get the Middle of the linked list and make it root.
2) Recursively do same for left half and right half.
       a) Get the middle of left half and make it left child of the root
          created in step 1.
       b) Get the middle of right half and make it right child of the
          root created in step 1.
```

**Code**

```
public Node bstToDll(Node root ){
        if(root!=null){
            Node lefthead = bstToDll(root.left); // traverse down to left 
            Node righthead = bstToDll(root.right); // traverse down to right
            Node temp = null;
            /*
             * lefthead represents head of link list created in left of node
             * righthead represents head of link list created in right
             * travel to end of left link list and add the current node in end
             */
            if(lefthead != null) {
                temp = lefthead;
                while(temp.next != null){
                    temp = temp.next;
                }
                temp.next = root;
            }else{
                lefthead = root;
            }
            root.prev = temp;
            /*
             *set the next node of current root to right head of right list
             */
            if(righthead != null){
                root.next = righthead;
                righthead.prev = root;
            }else{
                righthead = root;
            }
            return lefthead;// return left head as the head of the list added with current node
        }
        return null;
}
```

But this is not the most optimized way since the time complexity is O(nlogn). For a better optimized solution take a look at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-linked-list-to-balanced-bst/